# Construct k-edge connected subgraph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose I have grid graph with size m x n. The number of vertices is mn and the number of edges is 2mn-m-n. How to construct a connected subgraph with k-edge? I know since k is the number of edge, then mn-1 <= k <= 2mn-m-n. If k = mn-1, then the subgraph is a spanning tree. If k = 2mn-m-n, then the subgraph is the grid graph itself.

My approach is to first construct a spanning tree using Kruskal algorithm (to make sure it is connnected) and add k edge to that spanning tree. I am curious if is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for a count of the number of different spanning trees? A way to enumerate them?

Comment: No, I am asking how to construct a k-edge connected subgraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of spanning subgraphs of the type of lattice grid graph you're interested in. If you just want one one of these, you could connect each vertex it its horizontal neighbor(s), and connect the leftmost column (so this would end up looking like a comb. E.g.,

```
*-*-*-*-*
|
*-*-*-*-*
|
*-*-*-*-*
|
*-*-*-*-*
```

This is just one of many possible spanning subgraphs.

Finish by adding the necessary edges to get to k. The edge set can be described without being generated, as explained in the comments.

Comment: How does this help in generating a graph with *k* edges?

Comment: It's faster than Kruskal. Then add edges to get up to k.

Comment: E.g., add edges in order by filling in the vertical edges from left to right, top to bottom. This can be described without running any algorithm. I.e., if s is the number of extra edges (beyond the min spanning tree) then we can say that two vertices are adjacent if: 1) they're horizontal neighbors, 2) they're vertical neighbors in the first column, 3) they're vertical neighbors and the top vertex (x,y) satisfies x>=1, and (x-1) + (m-1)*y <= s. (assuming the upper left coord is (0,0))

Comment: Ah, so this is simply a cheaper way to generate a spanning tree. Without your first comment, the answer doesn't seem to address the question. I suggest adding it to the answer.